# webdriver manager update only to chrome driver version 114

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, protractor

I am still using protractor for automated testing. I got the latest chrome driver version 116 and chrome browser version 116.

I tried running `npx @puppeteer/browsers install chrome@stable` to get the latest chrome driver version 116.  I run `webdriver-manager update` to get chromedriver version 116 but it is still updating as 114.
Can anyone got any idea how to update it?

Comment: I have the same issue, from looking at https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/ the last update was for version 114.0.5735.90 on 2023-05-31. This version worked for me on version 115 but following an update to 116 this version of the driver no longer works.

Comment: `Try getting from here https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

Comment: I got the latest 116 version but webdriver manager update is still updating 114.

Comment: Found the fix now. Here it is https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/517#issuecomment-1673232896